# Adobe Reader re-installation error

Tags: installation, package-management, adobe, adobe-reader

I've installed Adobe Reader from bin file

```
cd "to directory"

sudo "bin file"
```

It was working but I've decided to add repos of Acroread so I uninstalled Reader dropping to terminal uninstall file localized in `/opt/Adobe/Reader9/bin/`

After typing into terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ raring partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install acroread

an error occured in 
 /var/cache/apt/archives/acroread-bin_9.5.5-1raring1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After that error synaptic notification appeared that some packages are broken so I Edit->Repair and next error occurred:

```
E: /var/cache/apt/archives/acroread-bin_9.5.5-1raring1_i386.deb: trying to overwrite "/opt/Adobe/Reader9/bin/acroread", which is also in package adobereader-enu 9.5.5
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You have two packages which are conflicting. This is a bug of the new package. Does removing the old one help? `sudo apt-get remove adobereader-enu 9.5.5`. The main Ubuntu packages in the repositories are checked against such errors, but installing from external sources can cause this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any adobereader-enu 9.5.5 package but this fixed my problem:

> sudo dpkg --purge adobereader-enu